# What is the tense of the verb that goes in "I wish I would do something that ..." ? (I wish I would buy him a present that he likes/liked.)

Tags: grammar, tenses

I was watching a TV show, and this girl said:

> I just wish that once, I'd bring a guy home that they actually **liked**.

Shouldn't it be like this? :

> I just wish that once, I'd bring a guy home that they actually **like**.

Didn't she mean '*I wish they'd like my future boyfriends*'?

I think this is OK:

> I just wish that once, I *brought* a guy home that they actually *liked*.

But the way she said it sounds strange to me.

Comment: Isn't it "Big Bang Theory"? I also thought it sounded weird when I first heard it. But there are a lot of grammatical mistakes in the show. I think *liked* should be changed to *like/will like*.

Comment: @Rathony No, it's correct as it stands. *Wish* takes a backshifted conjecture.

Comment: @tchrist Please see the below answer. Grammatically speaking, there should be an object after *liked* for the sentence to work in a subjunctive mood.

Comment: @Rathony I cannot see why you think there has to be an object, nor why you think the sentence as written is somehow ungrammatical.

Comment: In order for the object of *like* to be omitted, "that" should work as a relative pronoun. In order for *that* to be a conjunction which follows wish (I am assuming that you also think of *that* as a conjunction ), the object of *liked* should not be omitted as like is a transitive verb.

Comment: Or, better, [Tense change: previous actions on something that's currently true](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16388/tense-change-previous-actions-on-something-thats-currently-true).

Comment: @tchrist I know that *wish* takes a backshifted conjecture (hence the final example) , but not after *would*.

Comment: I remember a debate over a fairly demanding related question at school. It turned out that the accepted version of 'If a person should wish to succeed, he would have to work as hard as he ____.' needed _can_ rather than _could_. Note the deliberate 'needed'. This was almost 50 years ago.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You shared useful links, but I'm afraid they're not applicable here. Here I'm not talking about a timeless condition. In what I quoted, the girl wants her guy to be liked and accepted at that moment, as her boyfriend, not generally as a person.

Comment: @tchrist tom, shouldn't the "that" be replaced with "whom?"

Comment: I suppose logically, 'I wish that just once, I'd bring a guy home that/who they would actually like.' has the best correspondence. The two sentence (if one includes fragments) version is obviously correct: 'I wish that just once, I'd bring the right guy home.  A guy they would actually like.'

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence is correct.

You are correct in your assertion but the sentence also uses the past tense '-ed' to inform us that it has happened before.

i.e. she has brought back a guy home more than once and her parents did not like them and she wishes they they would for once.

Comment: This isn't quite right. What’s happening is that backshifting is being used in *liked* because wish takes a hypothetical conjecture, so it has to be in the past tense. There is no definitive implication of repetition or previous occurrence.

Comment: @tchrist sounds right to me.

Answer (score 0):

In a comedy show, sometimes grammatical principles are not strictly followed to make people laugh.

The sentence would be clearer if rephrased to:

> **If (once)** I'd bring a guy home, I just wish that they actually liked him.

I just wish that once, I'd bring a guy home ***that*** they actually liked.

Here, ***that*** seems to be used as a "*relative pronoun*" as the object of the verb *liked* is missing. However, it is not difficult to understand that *liked* is backshifted in a *I wish* construction which uses a subjunctive mood.

Comment: Shouldn't "that" be replaced with "who" since we're talking about a person?

Comment: @michael_timofeev *That* can be used in place of who / which that are objective and subjective relative pronouns except for a few cases, one **of which** is when "preposition" is used before whom/which. You can't use *that* after **of**.

Comment: I dunno...the sentence in yellow seems kinda fishy...

Comment: Ok but then shouldn't who be whom?

Comment: In other words, whom becomes the object of liked...

Comment: @michael_timofeev Unless there is preposition before it, who and that can be both used as an objective relative pronoun.

Comment: I understand but that doesn't have an object case and who does, so using whom solves the object of liked problem...I'm using the original sentence not the one in yellow.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean.  I think you and tom are both right.  I think it should be liked but that should be replaced with whom.

Comment: @michael_timofeev If you have a specific question regarding whom/that, please post your question.

Comment: I didn't vote for any answer.  I'm just trying to understand your point.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Please post your own question.