# Mixing past and present tense

Tags: indirect-speech, sequence-of-tenses

Today while reading the newspaper I found two sentences with the opposite pattern of tense usage.

Sentence 1 (Indirect speech) : 
A senior police officer said that the cumulative rents paid for some of these buildings are enough to purchase a land and build a police station.

The direct speech must have been like this - 
A senior police officer said, "The cumulative rents paid for some of these buildings are enough to purchase a land and build a police station".

Sentence 2 (Indirect speech) : 
The girl said that she wanted some ice water.

The direct speech must have been like this - 
The girl said, "I want some ice water".

My query was, why in sentence 1 'are' was not changed to 'were' although in sentence 2 'want' was changed to 'wanted' because in school we were taught that while converting direct speech to indirect speech, tenses are back shifted.

I looked up this query on Google and I learned that even 'are' is also correct in indirect speech of sentence 1. 
So by this logic, is it correct to use 'want' in indirect speech of sentence 2 ?

Thank you!

Comment: Related question, [“He didn't know where New Jersey was”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/he-didnt-know-where-new-jersey-was) and [Tense change: previous actions on something that's currently true](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16388/tense-change-previous-actions-on-something-thats-currently-true).

Answer (score 1):

You can use them together if whatever is being described is true today as much as it was in the past.

For instance:

> Archimedes **discovered** that the upward buoyant force that **is** exerted on a body immersed in a fluid **is** equal to the weight of the fluid that the body **displaces**.

As for your Sentence 1, a better way of putting it would be:

> A senior police officer said that the cumulative rents paid for some of these buildings **would be** enough to [...]